# How to remove the FMX section from Delphi's manual?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, chm

Delphi's help give LOTS of not-so-useful results. For example, if you are in a VCL project and press F1 on `TImage`, it will take you to `FMX` page for `TImage`.

How do remove the whole `FMX` section from Delphi's help?

Comment: For me, it's always prompted me to choose which help to view. Which is still a pain, since it *should* know what I want to see based on what I have open, but I've never seen it decide for me... Which version of Delphi?

Comment: FWIW, In my Delphi 10.1 Berlin, I tested your exact scenario, and it opened directly to the `Vcl` documentation. So, please let us know your Delphi version.

Comment: The help is project-type-sensitive, i.e. if you have a VCL project open, it'll go to VCL help, if an FMX project, to the FMX help. It appears the project also needs to have been saved first.

Comment: On that note, if you have *two* projects open, where one is VCL and the other is FMX, I would think it would depend on the *currently selected* project.

Comment: In the past I had similar problem after applying wrong update for help system. So I had to completely uninstall the help system and reinstall it.

Comment: @SilverWarior-this might be my problem. I will do so. Thanks.